A question about q-binomials at roots of unity
I have a question about a lemma $9.3.6$ in the book A Guide to Quantum Groups written by Vyjayanthi Chari and Andrew Pressley. This question comes from page 301, "The restricted specialization".
Here is the lemma:

Let $\epsilon$ be a primitive $\ell$th root of unity, where $\ell$ is odd  and greater than one. Let $r,s\in \mathbb{N}$ and write $r=r_0+\ell r_1,s=s_0+\ell s_1$, where $0\le r_0,s_0<\ell$, $r_1,s_1\ge 0$, $r\ge s$. Then $$\left[ \begin{array}{c}
    r\\
    s\\
\end{array} \right] _{\varepsilon}=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
    r_0\\
    s_0\\
\end{array} \right] _{\varepsilon}\left( \begin{array}{c}
    r_1\\
    s_1\\
\end{array} \right).$$
where $\left( \begin{array}{c}
    r_1\\
    s_1\\
\end{array} \right)$ is an ordinary binomial coefficient

Here are some notations:
\begin{align}
[n]_q& =\frac{q^n-q^{-n}}{q-q^{-1}}, \\
[n]_q!& =[n]_q.[n-1]_q\cdots [2]_q.[1]_q, \\
\left[\begin{array}{c}m\\n\end{array}\right]_q& =\frac{[m]_q!}{[n]_q![m-n]_q!}. 
\end{align}
Here is my question:
Since $\epsilon$ is a primitive $\ell$th root of unity, then I think $[l]_\varepsilon$ equals to $0$.
So the denominator will have $0$. Does this lemma make sense?
I am confused about it.
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

In my copy of the book is says $0\le r_0,s_0<\ell$.

There is an important fact that $q$-binomials are Laurent polynomials in $q$, so you may substitute every non-zero $q$

@DaveBenson Thank you. I have edited it.

@FedorPetrov Should I  replace $q$ with $\varepsilon$ in the final  Laurent polynomials in q?

This is often called the $q$-Lucas theorem (see e.g. https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/q-analogues.htm#prelimQanalogsQLucas). As Fedor said these are polynomials (or Laurent polynomials because of the quantum groups convention) so plugging in anything makes sense. But also, even if you want to leave it as a rational expression, yes you get some $0$'s in the denominator, but you get more $0$'s in the numerator which cancel. Maybe even another elementary way to think about it is: use L'Hôpital's rule.

@SamHopkins Thank  you.  It is helpful.

Since $s_0$ and $r_0-s_0$ are less than $\ell$, I don't see any $[\ell]_\varepsilon$ in the denominator.

@DaveBenson but the evaluation of the $q$-binomial on the LHS of the identity in the lemma may indeed have 0’s in the denominator. Anyways this question has been answered in multiple ways in the comments, and I don’t think it’s on topic for MO to begin with.

Oh yes, I see. Thanks. I agree.
